# Placeholder text on a disabled input field in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, input, placeholder

Are there any jQuery plugins or other methods by which to add placeholder text to a *disabled* input field in IE?

In particular, I've tried both [Replaceholder](http://designindevelopment.com/plugins/replaceholder-jquery-plugin/) and [Sparkle](http://balupton.github.com/jquery-sparkle/demo/) (which includes a placeholder polyfill). With either one, disabling an input field via script causes its placeholder text to disappear.

I could try hacking something together, but are there any scripts or plugins that support this out of the box?

Comment: I don't understand the issue? If you have an element like `<input type="text" disabled="disabled"/>`, and you want to put text inside of that, you can simply do `$('input[type=text]').val("Some Placeholder Text...");`

Comment: I'm using a script to add placeholder support for IE; in other words, so I can do `<input type="text" placeholder="Search" />` and have that work in IE automatically. The scripts I've tried cause the placeholder to disappear if I disable the field.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer

Comment: @daGUY [so what you're saying is you want this?](http://jsfiddle.net/DauFf/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes, but in IE! Try that in IE and you'll see the input has no placeholder text.