# Internet Explorer 10 and 11 remove placeholder text when the input is focused

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

When using Internet Explorer 10 and 11, input placeholder text is removed if the input is focused using the `autofocus` attribute. For example:

```
<input type="textbox" value="" placeholder="Example text" autofocus>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ompkwtz5/

How can I ensure the placeholder text isn't removed?

Ref: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/885747/ie-11-fires-the-input-event-when-a-input-field-with-placeholder-is-focused

Comment: Also IE9, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer/7225820

Comment: @KevinHakanson I think IE9 is slightly different. It doesn't support placeholders at all whereas 10 and 11 support them. 10 and 11 just handle them in a crazy way (they're removed when the input is focused).

Comment: you are correct, that answer linked to polyfills that work in both IE9, 10 and 11 to get expected behavior

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution only with css.
https://jsfiddle.net/nikdko/grc6v03a/

PS:withs input:valid + .fakePlaceholder {display:none  } ie gets freeze

```
<input type="text" pattern=".+" required="" />
<span class = "fakePlaceholder">Fake placeholder />

input {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index: 1;
}
.fakePlaceholder{
    color: #7D838A;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
input:valid {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[It's an IE bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445891/keep-placeholder-on-focus-in-ie10), the one in your reference link.

Take a look at [jquery-placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder). Will also support IE6! I'm not sure if it will work out of the box though, because IE10 is supposed to support the `placeholder` attribute, so check if `jQuery.fn.placeholder.input` is `true` (more info in the [README](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder#notes)). If it is, the plugin won't do anything, so you might need to override its checking behaviour.

Amazing that the bug is still active.

Comment: I noticed that; shame they haven't been able to provide a fix.