# AngularJS ng-attr-placeholder doesn't work in input type text

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, placeholder

I realised that placeholder attribute in Internet Explorer 11 does not work when the cursor is on (what a surprise!) despite that [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) says it is compatible with ie10+ (even though their [try it yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder) example does not work well in ie).

This is what users see when they want to login:

[image]

so I found about [ng-attr-placeholder](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) instead but I cannot seem to make it work.

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" ng-attr-placeholder="Password" required="" autofocus="">
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try again - `placeholder` works fine in IE10 in the "try it yourself" example. And `ng-attr-` wouldn't have fixed it anyway, if it wasn't. All it does is append the attribute with the interpolated value

Comment: Not if the cursor is on it unfortunately, anyway i decided to remove autofocus="" in order to disable cursor being automatically on username input

Comment: This is working as designed for IE. See this other post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445891/keep-placeholder-on-focus-in-ie10