# Obtain user coordinates with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

need your help.

I am not sure what I am doing, and I also mix jQuery and JS together to an extend which is simply not making any sense, but I don't know what to do and how to approach this issue.

I want the `value` of the `#third-input` in my `form` to be updated with the coordinates once `form` was `submitted`.

```
<form class="flex-form" action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input id="first-input" type="text" placeholder="What is your name?" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'What is your name?'" value="" name="name">
<br />
<input id="second-input" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Enter your phone number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your phone number'" value="" name="phone-number">
<br />
<input id="third-input" type="text" placeholder="Press button and Share location" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Press button and Share location'" value="" disabled="disabled" name="coordinates">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send Us Request">
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery for this form

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  var name = $('#first-input').val();
  var telephone = $('#second-input').val();
  var location = $('#third-input').val();


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
    location.val() = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

    }

    function showPosition(position) {
    location.val(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);  

    }



  if(name === ''){
    $('#first-input').css('border-top', 'solid 5px #ED6D60');
  } else {
    $('#first-input').css('border-top', 'solid 5px #0ED54D');
  }

  if(telephone === ''){
    $('#second-input').css('border-top', 'solid 5px #ED6D60');
  } else {
    $('#second-input').css('border-top', 'solid 5px #0ED54D');
  }

  if(location === ''){
    $('#third-input').css('border-top', 'solid 5px #ED6D60');
  } else {
    $('#third-input').css('border-top', 'solid 5px #0ED54D');
  }

  return false;
```

The Geolocation idea I took from this link [http://www.w3schools.com/][1]

As you can see, I am very new to it, but I can promise you that I made a healthy search and didn't find any solution. I would also like to avoid using plugins.

Thanks.

Code with comments is welcome, I just want to be sure "what does what".

[1]: Geolocation on w3schools.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like your javascript code is cut of or missing some `{` or `}`
2. May i suggest to add the [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) to the input field instead of having to check it manually? Then you can use the [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) and [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) pseudo class to style it.
3. `.val()` is a getter once you have that you got yourself the input value string. What you want to do is to use the setter method `.val("geo not supported")`

   - You can never assign a function to be something else. (`val() = ''`)
   - Removing the `.val();` from `$('#third-input').val();` should be sufficient
   - But i don't think you should set that value to a not-supported description as the field should only contain a location add that above or somewhere else
4. For the phone number field I would use the `tel` type instead of `text`
5. `<br>` is already self closing, so no need to add `/`.
6. IMO `placeholder` is not meant for labeling input fields. They should be used as example input (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445891/keep-placeholder-on-focus-in-ie10))
7. throwing in some [autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete) wouldn't be so bad either
8. if you don't like the placeholder when you focus on the input field then use css `:focus` + `::placeholder` to remove it instead of setting/removing the placeholder attribute on blur/focus

   - IMO I think it should be static and let that be left alone

Here is my solution all summarized: https://jsfiddle.net/1u8v0mam/1/

Comment: 100% spot on, thank a lot, I used and read through all your suggestions.