# Placeholder not showing up on IE with a ternary operation using React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

```
    getPlaceholder() {
        switch (this.props.field.dataType) {
            case 'DATE':
                return 'MM/DD/YYYY'
            case 'EMAIL':
                return 'myemail@email.com'
            default:
                return null
        }
}

render() {
 return(
     <div>
        <input placeholder={field.focused ? this.getPlaceholder() : null} />
     </div>
  )
}
```

filed.focused is coming from redux. Returns a Boolean letting me know if field is focused or not.

this.props.field.dataType returns a string with the datatype.

I **NEED** to show the placeholder only on **FOCUS**.

This works in safari, Chrome, Firefox, and even edge. But not working in IE11.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This appears to be a 'feature' in IE (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445891/keep-placeholder-on-focus-in-ie10)).