# Clearing the textbox values onclick and displaying onblur

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to clear the default textbox value onclick on textbox and display onblur of multiple textboxes on form page?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you want a placeholder-like behaviour? Is it a `textbox` or an `input`? What should be clicked? The textbox itself? Should it always be cleared? Or only under certain conditions?

Comment: Yes I want a placeholder kind of behaviour on multiple text boxes on a form page

Comment: You can use the HTML5 placeholder tag `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter something..." />` - is that want you want? (http://jsfiddle.net/fnkr/69pt9/)[Preview here]

Comment: Yes I know but it doesn't work in IE

Comment: @sahilagarwal: Again, `textbox` or `input`? Show some effort, include at least a little bit of your HTML in your question and what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function Clear1(str)
{    
   document.getElementById(str).value= "";
}

function Clear2(str2)
{    
var aa1=document.getElementById(str2);
 if (aa1.value==""){  
    document.getElementById(str2).style.backgroundColor = "#ffcccc"; 
 }else{
    document.getElementById(str2).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";   
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test1" onClick="Clear1(this.id);" id="textbox1" onblur="Clear2(this.id);">
<input type="text" value="test2" onClick="Clear1(this.id);" id="textbox2" onblur="Clear2(this.id);">
<input type="text" value="test3" onClick="Clear1(this.id);" id="textbox3" onblur="Clear2(this.id);">
<input type="text" value="test4" onClick="Clear1(this.id);" id="textbox4" onblur="Clear2(this.id);">
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/warunamanjula/qy0hvmyq/1/**

Answer (score 8):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" onClick="Clear();" id="textbox1>
<input type="text" value="" onClick="Clear();" id="textbox2>
<input type="text" value="" onClick="Clear();" id="textbox3>
<input type="text" value="" onClick="Clear();" id="textbox4>
```

Javascript :

```
function Clear()
{    
   document.getElementById("textbox1").value= "";
   document.getElementById("textbox2").value= "";
   document.getElementById("textbox3").value= "";
   document.getElementById("textbox4").value= "";
}
```

Your question was a little vague to me, but the above will clear all the textboxes when one is clicked. Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: DRY `function Clear(obj){obj.value=''}` and call `<input type="text" value="" onClick="Clear(this);" id="textbox1>`

Answer (score 5):

One Line solution

```
  <input type="text" value="" onClick="this.value='';" id="textbox1">
```

or

```
 <input type="text" value="" onClick="this.value=='Initial Text'?this.value='':this.value;" id="textbox1">
```

Comment: This will clear it every time, not just the default value. You probably need a flag to indicate that whether it's the first time or not.

Comment: `<input type="text" value="" onClick="this.value=='Initial Text'?this.value='':this.value;" id="textbox1">`