# The best placeholder polyfil script for ie7, ie8 and ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, polyfills

Which placeholder polyfill script do you recommend that I use to provide placeholder support in ie7, 8 & 9.

I've seen the following [list](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) from the modernizer team and was wondering if anybody here had some mileage with them or any others not on the list and what they think is the *best*

**My criteria for evaluation would be:**

- File Size
- Ability to work without modernizer/yepnope
- Speed (no crazy looping)
- Stability, how much as it been used in the wild?
- Detect native placeholder ability and not bother running

I remember a day when I used to write a line or so in the onclick event of an input for placeholder support - lol, but to be honest I can't bothered to support these horrible browsers ([watch this funny](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyGP0ZyxF5E)).  At least IE10 is finally moving in the right direction.

Thank you...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer ?

Comment: @JujharSingh it's not about being fair, it's about obeying the rules of SO.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I recommend you use the [jQuery Placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) polyfill by [Mathias Bynens](https://twitter.com/mathias).

- It supports IE6+
- It is 2k minified
- It does its own feature detection (Modernizr isn't needed)
- The code is straightforward. The jQuery selection will vary depending on your selector
- It is the one polyfill recommended by [HTML5Please](http://html5please.com) and is listed on the [Modernizr Wiki](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) you mentioned
- It doesn't execute the code if it isn't needed

Comment: do you know how to modify the color of the place holder?

Comment: Allan Chua: Add placeholder class in your own CSS. .placeholder{ color:red;}

Comment: The above library has an issue with placing the placeholder text in as the actual text after an Ajax call (using backbone/marionette). GitHub has the issue documented, but the code hasn't been touched in 6 months. Here's a link to the issue. https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/issues/196