# Floating Labels - IE Compatibility. Anyone know how to add compatibility for IE8 & IE9?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, placeholder

I'm using this plugin for my website:
http://headdetect.github.io/bootstrap-floating-labels/

The bootstrap floating labels plugin.

It's essentially placeholders.

However, it doesn't currently support IE8 / IE9. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to add support? I'm using Modernizr.js on my website, which I thought added support for that but I guess not.

Thanks.

Comment: Modernizr does not add support for anything other than the option to provide HTML5 shims (which allow you to use dom elements not previously known to IE).  Other than that it does feature detection and exposes the results as CSS classes set on the html object.  This allows you to target behavior based on detected features.  It does nothing to create or provide missing functionality.

Comment: Interesting. I did see that Modernizr.js has HTML5SHIV/SHIM bundled in it. And that adds support for missing functionality, right?

Comment: No. Older versions of IE essentially ignore unknown tags.  So if you tried to use <article> or <section> tags, for instance, IE would not allow you to style them at all since it basically didn't treat them as HTML tags.  The shim forces IE to recognize known HTML5 tags (tags that were added to the HTML spec) so that you can use them in older versions of IE as normal block tags.

Comment: Using "floating labels" like that is *horrible* UI design...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is IE9 and below not supporting the `placeholder` attribute.  What you need is a polyfill.  See this related post: [The best placeholder polyfil script for ie7, ie8 and ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436125/the-best-placeholder-polyfil-script-for-ie7-ie8-and-ie9)

Comment: Not sure what the installation thing is; "bower install jquery-placeholder". I don't have that level of access to run commands like that.

Comment: what are you referring to?  the polyfill is just jquery: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: Oh ok, the Installation section threw me off.