# Changing Font Size and Margin of Placeholder Text in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a text input with some placeholder:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder"/>
```

I would like to make the placeholder text smaller than the input's text:

```
input {
    font-size: 20px;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder{
    font-size:5px;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size:5px;
}
```

This works well in Chrome, but IE shrinks the whole input box when the placeholder text is displayed. It then expands the box when I click to type. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Brn6h/3/

How do I make the input box stay the same size in IE?

Comment: Check it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436125/the-best-placeholder-polyfil-script-for-ie7-ie8-and-ie9

Comment: does padding or width/height work with `input:-ms-input-placeholder`?

Answer (score 3):

Giving the input box a width and height does the trick.

```
input {
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 200px;
    }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Brn6h/5/)**