# Default text in asp.net textbox in password mode

Tags: asp.net, passwords

If I have an ASP textbox in password mode the text I enter is masked, but I would like to have the default text displayed as the word "Password" in the textbox, and when the user start to type in the password it should be masked, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the HTML `placeholder` attribute.

HTML

```
<input type="password" name="fname" placeholder="password">
```

ASP

```
<asp:textbox placeholder="password" runat="server" />
```

For versions of IE before 10, you need to [use a `placeholder` polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436125/the-best-placeholder-polyfil-script-for-ie7-ie8-and-ie9) to get full support.

Comment: if you need to consider older browsers , check out placeholder polyfills   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436125/the-best-placeholder-polyfil-script-for-ie7-ie8-and-ie9

Comment: Thanks that worked fine for chrome and firefox, but for IE I had to add this... https://github.com/UmbraEngineering/Placeholder