# HTML5 Placeholder is not working in windows phones?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML5 Placeholder is not working in windows phones?
Using HTML5 and Javascript a created a web appliacation which is working on all the devices, now getting problem that PlaceHolder is not working in Windows Phones,

Can anyone help me on this...

Thanks

Comment: See the actual browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

Comment: @JanTuroň — As far as I can tell, that site doesn't cover Windows Phone

Answer (score 1):

> HTML5 Placeholder is not working in windows phones?

Correct. It isn't a supported feature (at least in Windows Phone 7).

Make sure that any essential information needed to fill out the field is stored in a `<label>`.

Comment: With the exception of inputs which have built in labels (such as submit buttons), all input (and select and textarea) elements should be accompanied by a label. See also [this](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a workaround using javascript. like here: http://code.google.com/p/complete-placeholder/

Comment: Eugh, that script performs `value` abuse.

Comment: take a look at this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer ...or why not change to a newer jQuery version?

Comment: i changes to a newer ver of Jquery still getting problem

Comment: did you tried some jQuery placeholder plugin like this? https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js