# HTML5 input type placeholder is not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, placeholder

I am using HTML5 for one of my project. There I am using input placeholder property to show some default text. It's not working in IE. Any solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input placeholders for Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholder is not supported until IE 10.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

You can use a [polyfill](https://www.google.com/search?q=placeholder+polyfill) to support it in IE.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not supported. Can we write some function in java-script to achieve this.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal I answered that, and your question really should've noted that you were aware of the lack of support.

Comment: I got it. I have written a custom function and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using javascript in your project, you can add this peace of code and it will provide a placeholder through javascript to your inputs.

```
function supports_input_placeholder() {
        var i = document.createElement('input');
        return 'placeholder' in i;
    }

if (!supports_input_placeholder()) {
    var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].hasAttribute('placeholder')) {
            fields[i].defaultValue = fields[i].getAttribute('placeholder');
            fields[i].onfocus = function () { if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = ''; }
            fields[i].onblur = function () { if (this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that correct. But when you post the form you have to check at the server end also as it will have some value as per above code.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal inputs with attribute `placeholder` don't imply any kind of server-side activity: the above code will take whatever has been put as the `placeholder` attribute and make that behaviour work in non-supporting browsers. It solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

See the top answer on this thread as it has a very good explanation:
[Input placeholders for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Older version of IE don't support html placeholders. Therefore, you will need to use a javascript solution like [Placeholder.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/). It automatically detects the placeholder attributes in your input elements and utilizes a cross-browser solution to show them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery placeholder](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder). HTML5 placeholder is not supported by standard HTML5 declaration until Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: w3schools is often inaccurate, reductive and misleading and shouldn't be propagated as a reference (Google does that already). http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I know. I suggested him on a light way. Thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

try [Placeholders.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/)

it is light weight and also works well in IE 6

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option would be to show the "name:" text on IE < 10

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]><style>.show-ie{display:block;}</style><![endif]-->
```