# set placeholder for internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using the following code

`<input required type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name.." />`

but the placeholder value is not appearing in IE browser, please give me a solution or give me an alternative method.

Comment: See [this](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/). IE10 + will support that. Please check your IE version.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 and earlier [don't support the `placeholder` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder). It's in IE10+.

There are a number of JavaScript solutions out there, if you look for "placeholder shim" or similar. For instance, I did the [`place5` jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/place5/), but that won't help you if you don't use jQuery. But again, there are several others out there. [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer?lq=1) list several.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the placeholder displayed in IE browsers too. Use [this  plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder), it's probably the simplest method.

> Works in all A-grade browsers, including IE6.

Good luck!