# How to use autofocus without canceling placeholder in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I would like to use Autofocus and Placeholder in the same input Box. It works in most browsers except for Internet Explorer, the Autofocus cancels out the Placeholder. Could you tell me how to stop this from happening?**

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <input type="type" placeholder="PlaceHolder Text" autofocus="autofocus">  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at this and i think would help you a bit. [Try This](http://devproconnections.com/html5/working-html5-web-forms-autofocus-and-placeholder-attributes)

Comment: [or try this for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround with this:

http://samplacette.com/html-5-placeholder-autofocus-cross-browser-support-for-ie/

It explains the problem and gives you a polyfill to avoid it.

https://github.com/SamPlacette/placeholdr

good luck