# :-ms-input-placeholder is not working in IE9 in Windows 7 OS

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am really confused about a CSS problem in IE9 browser. I have a webpage with `textarea` element with `placeholder`. I want to `text-align: center;` the place-holder only,

[image]

input text text-align is set to left.

[image]

**Please see my edits below.**

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        textarea {
            width: 80%;
            height: 80px;
        }

        ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            text-align: center;
        }

        :-moz-placeholder {
            text-align: center;
        }

        ::-moz-placeholder {
            text-align: center;
        }

        :-ms-input-placeholder {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea rows="2" cols="21" id='txtnote' class="testplaceholder" maxlength="500" placeholder="Note" onblur=""></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine in **IE 11, Firefox, Chrome in Windows 8** , But when i look this webpage in to **IE9 in Windows 7**
it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx), in order for this selector to work you need to have at least IE 10.  Also, after further investigation -- since it is not supported in IE9 there are other workarounds to getting it to work as desired.

Please check out this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer) or this [**alternative JS here**](http://www.codinglover.com/cross-browser-styling-placeholder-placeholder-fixed-ie-8-ie-9/).

Comment: And this addresses the IE issue how, exactly? The -ms- prefix was already there, so at best this answer addresses the other browsers while conveniently ignoring the subject of the question - IE.

Comment: Originally the question didn't have those details, I have since adjusted my answer.  Thank you

Comment: @David Thank you for your great support.